# Make Constraint Deferrable in Oracle

Tags: oracle, database-design, constraints

In Oracle, is it possible to use syntax like `alter table 'TBL_NM' modify constraint 'CONSTRAINT_NM' ... deferrable` to make an existing constraint deferrable, or does the constraint have to be dropped and re-created as deferrable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has to be dropped and recreated.